# Getting correct direction from Android magnetic sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors

In android we get the reading from the magnetic sensor and determine the direction. But we know that the magnetic north is not true north. As a result there is deflection from the true north. Again this deflection is not same for all the places. Also in the same place the deflection is changing over time as the magnetic north is moving at a rate 40kms/year from true north. So, the data we get from the sensor is not usable without some correction.

Now i have two points A,B with their latitude, longitude , altitude like below figure. I need to determine the correct vector. As, my position is A and my direction from sensor is not correct i cannot get the correct vector X & Y from A to B. Is there any way to attain the correct vector by filtering the magnetic sensor data?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VAQ2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [GeomagneticField](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/GeomagneticField.html) in android which gives you the deflection from true north at your current position at current time. So you can get the deflection from true north with below code

```
gmf = new GeomagneticField((float) ur_Latitude(), 
                                       (float) ur_Longitude(),
                                       (float) ur_Altitude(), 
                                       System.currentTimeMillis());
            myAngle = Math.toRadians(-gmf.getDeclination());
```

Now you can rotate your vector in Y-axis through this angle `myAngle`

Comment: Let me see if it works. btw How can i rotate the vector through Y-axis??

Comment: You need to ask a separate question if you want to know anything more @ShohelRayhan